# Copy file from directory to another using ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder

After iterate field value and get the 4 sheets I want,

[image]

[image]

Now I want to search about the images that have the same name of the sheet  in origin folder and export them to a folder or gdb.

[image]

Here is the model I have built:

[image]

but it is not working. I don’t know the proper wildcard to use to get the same name from the images folder.

Comment: You had ArcPy in your title and tags but did not include a code attempt in your question body so I have removed them to keep this focused on ModelBuilder.

Comment: in case someone need to answer with them, thank you

Answer (score 2):

You were on the right track of using sub-models but the logic is flawed and its not clear if you are using in-line variable substitution?

I've spoofed up a folder of images (in my case they a BMP), importantly that all have a consistent naming convention, the sheet number is at the end, which looks like what you have too.

[image: Sample data]

I have a MASTER model with a sub-model. The master is this:

[image: Master]

The sub-model is this:

[image: Sub model]

In the sub-model there is only one iterator, the field value which would be working on the selection. The Calculate Value tool is used to construct a full path to the raster dataset and is set up as:

[image: calculate Value tool]

It is using in-line variable substitution to pass the sheet no text into the file path name and its output is a raster dataset, this allows its output to feed into the Copy Raster tool.

I use the in-line variable substitution again in the Copy Raster tool as show below:

[image: Copy Raster tool]